# Add music to the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

As the title says i m trying to put music into android emulator to play them using the android music player.

Comment: In the DDMS perspective, put your files into `/system/media/audio/ringtones/`. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> play them using the android music player.

The simplest approach would be to add SD card to your emulator and then put your music files there.

Answer (score 3):

Just drag and drop the Music file in to the emulator. It will show in the Files-Download.